# WPF: How to Style my form with Transperancy levels

Tags: wpf, colors, winobjc

I want to implement this kind of `Window`:

[image]

So currently i have this `Style` :

```
<Window x:Class="CGTransparent.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AboutDlg"
    Opacity="0.75"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True" Height="300"
                      Width="500"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    Background="#00000000">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradientBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#202020" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="#303030" Offset="0.50" />
            <GradientStop Color="#404040" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="#505050" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border CornerRadius="15" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="{DynamicResource GradientBrush}" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <Grid Margin="0" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Result (ignore the tiger...):

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this example `Style` ?

**Update**:

```
<Window x:Class="app.Forms.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PacketPlayer.Forms"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="20">
        <Grid>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\racr\Desktop\download.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-60">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="60" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <Border CornerRadius="60" Margin="30" Background="#7F000000">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Run Text="Hello World" FontSize="48"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="walterlv.github.io"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFPhj.png)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simulate your original image with only `GradientBrush`, you should blur an image with a large amount of blur radius.

---

### Options to simulate it

It's sad to tell you that you **cannot** implement the iOS blur style exactly as it shows for you.

But, we have three other methods to simulate this kind of style (on Windows 10) and each has its advantages and disadvantages.

1. Call the Windows internal API `SetWindowCompositionAttribute`. You can get a lightly blurred transparent Window but this transparency is much less than the iOS one.
   [image: The image from my post]
2. Add a `BlurEffect` to the window background image. You can get a more similar visual effect like the iOS one with very poor performance. But in this way, the background image is fixed and cannot be updated when the window moves.
   [image: BlurEffect of WPF]
3. Use UWP instead of WPF and use the `AcrylicBrush`. You can get a high-performance blur transparent window. But you should try the UWP Application development.
   [image: The UWP AcrylicBrush from learn.microsoft.com]

---

### How to implement them

#### SetWindowCompositionAttribute API

Calling `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` API is not very easy, so I've written a wrapper class for easier usage. You can use my class by writing only a simple line in the XAML file **or** in the cs file.

```
<Window x:Class="CGTransparent.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:interop="clr-namespace:Walterlv.Demo.Interop"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="AboutDlg" Height="350" Width="525"
    interop:WindowBlur.IsEnabled="True"
    Background="Transparent">
</Window>
```

Or you can use it in the cs file like this:

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowBlur.SetIsEnabled(this, true);
    }
}
```

Just add my wrapper class into your project. It's a very long class so I pasted into GitHub: https://gist.github.com/walterlv/752669f389978440d344941a5fcd5b00.

I also write a post for its usage, but it's not in English: https://walterlv.github.io/post/win10/2017/10/02/wpf-transparent-blur-in-windows-10.html

#### WPF BlurEffect

Just set the Effect property of a WPF UIElement.

```
<Window x:Class="MejirdrituTeWarqoudear.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        Width="540" Height="360">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="YourImageFile.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-60">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="60" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <Border CornerRadius="60" Margin="30" Background="#7F000000">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Run Text="Hello World" FontSize="48"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="walterlv.github.io"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that it has a very poor performance.

#### UWP AcyclicBrush

You can read Microsoft's documents [Acrylic material - UWP app developer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) for more details about how to write an `AcylicBrush`.

### Update

You can add a `RectangleGeometry` to clip your UIElement into a rounded rectangle.

[image: Rounded Rectangle]

```
<Window x:Class="MejirdrituTeWarqoudear.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="540" Height="360">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="60" RadiusY="60" Rect="30 30 480 300" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <Image Source="High+Sierra.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-60">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect KernelType="Gaussian" Radius="60" />
            </Image.Effect>
        </Image>
        <Border Background="#7F000000">
            <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                       FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" TextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Run Text="Hello World" FontSize="48"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="walterlv.github.io"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I didn't mention that I need background image, I very like your second window example, the performance is not so important because this window is opened as child one for few seconds.

Comment: I can get this style using your WPF BlurEffect example?

Comment: @DalRaz, of course, you can even take them all. I'm glad I can help you.

Comment: Just need to get home in order to test it on my computer, BTW why it impossible to get this  iOS style?

Comment: I just saw that you mentioned that this can be only on Windows 10, what about windows 7?

Comment: @DalRaz, the 1st and 3rd one are both Windows 10 only. But the 2nd one can be used for Windows 7/8/8.1/10.

Comment: I try your code and it seems not working, please see my update

Comment: Please see my update again, just need to add rounded corners, all the rest fine.

Comment: @DalRaz, I added a `RectangleGeometry` to clip the whole UIElement. It's not flexible in the code above, but if you want it more flexible, you can read my post.

Comment: Good, but why don't you write a blog?

Comment: Good, but why don't you write a blog?

Comment: @lindexi I followed your suggestion and write a new blog: https://walterlv.github.io/post/create-blur-background-window-en.html

Comment: There are issues with trying to implement this example, the dependency of .NET 3.x framework and PresentationFramework and dll is not mentioned. Missing needed namespaces as well. The code still fails for other reasons during compilation.

"An expression of type 'DependencyObject' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'Window'."

Comment: @RBenR It seems that your project is NOT a WPF project. For an SDK style project, you should use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` as your Sdk and `UseWpf` should be set to `true`.